# Store filter in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have store having structure :

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: [
        'title'
    ],
    data: [{
        title: 'ABC'
    }, {
        title: 'ABC2'
    }, {
        title: 'ABC3'
    }, {
        title: 'ABC4'
    }, {
        title: 'ABC5'
    }, {
        title: 'ABC6'
    }]
});
```

So when I load this store List get populated with all 6 records.

I just wanted to Filter this store on button click I just wanted to get some selected record out of this 6 record Can It be possible.

Provide me Some Idea or Working code.

Comment: select records based on title ?

Comment: Actually I wanted to display this record on list view ...Can you please provide working code or some frame code... Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To filter the store based on title

```
Ext.getStore('storeId').filter("title", "ABC3");
```

To clear filter

```
 Ext.getStore('storeId').clearFilter();
```

See store [filter](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter) doc

**Update**

```
Ext.getStore('storeId').filterBy(function(record){
   var title = record.get('title');
   if(title == "ABC" || title == "ABC1" || title == "ABC2")
      return record;
});
```

Comment: This way I will just get single record on list view i.e "ABC3" but I want to get Multiple records but Not all..Thanks for your response

Comment: @VInayak Multiple records based on what ?

Comment: Multiple records means when I use following code Ext.getStore('storeId').filter("title", "ABC3"); On list view I get only single title as "ABC3" But actually I want to get ABC ABC1 ABC2 on list view not all.Sorry for giving you so much trouble and thanks for your response.

Comment: @VInayak for that type of condition you need to use filterBy.. see the Update in my answer

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to set a filter on the store when I tap on the button. In my case it was a selectfield and on the change event I filter compared to the current value in the selectfield

```
    onChangeStatusSelectfield: function (newValue, oldValue) {
    var store = Ext.getStore('CustomVacationRequest');
    console.log('Accepted Filter');
    newValue = this.getStatusSelectfield().getValue();
    console.log(store, newValue);
    store.clearFilter();
    if (store != null);
    store.filter(function (record) {
        if (newValue == record.data.status) { //your data from the store compared to 
                                              //the value from the selectfield
            return true; 
        }
        Ext.getCmp("VacationRequestsManagerList").refresh() //refresh your list   
});

},
```

This is just my part of the controller. Handle events and buttons and stores at your own choice&need. Good luck!