# Store filter in sencha touch (multiple items)

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, store

I saw this question and I want to go a step further
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606212/store-filter-in-sencha-touch#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606212/store-filter-in-sencha-touch#_=_)

First I filter that table (this is working so far):
[image: Table 1]

Then I will filter another table depending on the filter of the first table.
[image: Table 2]

Result will be either:
[image: Table 2 Filter 1 green]

or (for example):
[image: Table 2 Filter 2 yellow]

And now I tested something like:

```
TABLEVIEWSTORE1.filter("name", name);

   TABLEVIEWSTORE1.load({callback: function (){
       tableviewstore2.load({callback: function (){

       TABLEVIEWSTORE1.each(function(item){
           tableviewstore2.filterBy(function(record,id){
               return record.get("number") == item.get("number");
           }, this);
       });

        TABLEVIEWSTORE1.load({callback: function (){
            tableviewstore2.load({callback: function (){
                    // DO MORE THINGS
            }});
        }});
           }});

    }});
});
```

Has anyone an idea how it can be working properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly we should find all the unique numbers from the first filtered store.
Then, we should filter the second store based on those unique numbers array.
We will use `Ext.Array` for this.

```
var uniqueNumbers= [];       
    TABLEVIEWSTORE1.each(function(item){
             Ext.Array.include(uniqueNumbers,item);
    });
    tableviewstore2.filterBy(function(record){
                   return Ext.Array.contains(uniqueNumbers,record.get("number"));
               });
```

Comment: it works. Thank you so much :)
I only changed 
Ext.Array.include(uniqueNumbers,item.get("number"));